# Integrate Django authentication with Enterprise Identity Provider PingFederate

Tags: python, django, saml-2.0, pingfederate

We developed web apps in django framework. We have an enterprise Identity Provider which is PingFederate. The main home page (which is different from our site) from chrome browser and edge browser directly recognizes the user and logs them in all the internal websites. We are also on the same network share same domain. We also want to integrate SSO and want to authenticate our users directly with asking password. I researched every where and got to know the authentication is happening by kerbose authentication. Somehow the edge or chrome  is sending some token or id or some TGT ticket to the Identity Provider then they will authenticate and send the username back to the client browser. Can any one please help me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem and wrote an article about it. Please feel free to see that article.
https://medium.com/@manishkumar.bobbili3/how-i-integrated-ping-identity-with-django-web-framework-for-single-sign-on-sso-9be21b953bc5

Comment: Is there a repo you can share for what you did?  I read the article but would love to see a code example.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to integrate with the PingFederate solution to use it as the identity provider and allow the users of your web apps to login through SSO. If that is the case, you would need to work with whoever responsible for PingFedereate if it is another team.

**Checklist with the PingFederate Admin**

- You would need to know if you need to choose the directory will be used to log the users in.
- Which user attributes you would need to get back in the SAML response.
- Will you sign the SAML request using your app or not.
- Will you start the SSO cycle from your app, which I believe you would, and you will be using SP initiated in this case.

Otherwise, it will be the other way around and will be using IDP Initiated.

- SP Initiated - User will call the app URL first and then redirected
  to Ping URL and be sent back to the app.
- IDP Initiated - User will call PingFederate URL and will be sent to the app after authentication.

I will list the steps in here in case it is your team who is also responsible for PingFederate solution:

- **Changes in PingFederate as SP (service provider) connection**

  1. Create a new IDP (Identity Provider) Adapter for the login page if needed.

     1. IDP adapter will be using a Password Credential Validator to do the authentication and also has the configuration for which HTML pages to present to the user.
     2. Create the SP connection in Ping with the stuff in the check list.

        1. The connection here will use the adapter in the step above to present the login page
        2. Then check the user credentials and establish the SSO session if successful.
        3. Assemble the SAML response with all the required attributes.
        4. Sign the response and send it to the application endpoint configured inside the connection.
- **Changes in the web app as the service provider for the user**

  1. The application will need to send the SAML request to the endpoint of the new connection in Ping.
  2. Wait for the response on the dedicated endpoint.
  3. Verify the SAML response signature using the PingFederate server's public key.
  4. Create the local app session and move on.

If you will be using OpenToken, this will change to have another interaction of Adapter-to-Adapter. Just reply with that if this is the case.